# Call clear costmap service periodically

Tags: ros, laser, ros-kinetic, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I have the ROS navigation package on Kinetic with a Realsense camera. I am transforming the depth image of the camera to laser scan, and then with that laser scan generate obstacles with the costmap_2d package. The problem arrives when the obstacle gets closer to my robot and it generates lots of marks of obstacles and it does not clear the old ones. I have the marking and clearing parameters set to true as you can see in the following code snippet:

```
laser_layer: #Laser
  #track_unknown_space: false
  #footprint_clearing_enabled: true
  #combination_method: 1
  observation_sources:  laser
  laser:
    topic: /scan
    sensor_frame: camera_depth_frame
    #observation_persistance: 0.0
    expected_update_rate: 0
    data_type: LaserScan
    clearing: true
    marking: true
    #max_obstacle_height: 2.0
    #min_obstacle_height: 0.0
    obstacle_range: 3.0
    raytrace_range: 3.5
    #inf_is_invalid: false
```

I want to call the clear costmap service periodically (for example each 500ms) to clean the obstacles and solve the problem, but I don't the way to call it in order to make it works.

I know I must call something like this:

```
std_srvs::Empty srv;
clear_costmaps_client.call(srv)
```

But i don't know in which script or .cpp file (move_base.cpp or obstacle_layer.cpp maybe?).

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.
Alessandro

EDIT

Finally I solved it using other type of layer (Spatio Temporal Voxel Layer) and generating a mark layer with the LaserScan topic with a voxel decay of 0.75 seconds. The configuration of the layer is the following:

```
laser_layer_temp:
  enabled:               true
  voxel_decay:           0.75     #seconds if linear, e^n if exponential
  decay_model:           0      #0=linear, 1=exponential, -1=persistent
  voxel_size:            0.05   #meters
  track_unknown_space:   true   #default space is unknown
  observation_persistence: 0.0  #seconds
  max_obstacle_height:   2.0    #meters
  unknown_threshold:     15     #voxel height
  mark_threshold:        0      #voxel height
  update_footprint_enabled: true
  combination_method:    1      #1=max, 0=override
  obstacle_range:        3.0    #meters
  origin_z:              0.0    #meters
  publish_voxel_map:     true   # default off
  transform_tolerance:   0.2    # seconds
  mapping_mode:          false  # default off, saves map not for navigation
  map_save_duration:     60     #default 60s, how often to autosave
  observation_sources:    rgbd1_mark
  rgbd1_mark:
    data_type: LaserScan
    topic: /scan
    marking: true
    clearing: false
    #min_obstacle_height: 0.3     #default 0, meters
    #max_obstacle_height: 2.0     #defaule 3, meters
    expected_update_rate: 0.0    #default 0, if not updating at this rate at least, remove from buffer
    observation_persistence: 0.0 #default 0, use all measurements taken during now-value, 0=latest
    inf_is_valid: false          #default false, for laser scans
    clear_after_reading: true    #default false, clear the buffer after the layer gets readings from it
    voxel_filter: true           #default off, apply voxel filter to sensor, recommend on
    voxel_min_points: 0          #default 0, minimum points per voxel for voxel filter
```

Best regards.
Alessandro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347490/call-clear-costmap-service-periodically/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2020-03-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-03-27**:
I tried this on terminal and it worked:

```
rosservice call /move_base/clear_costmaps "{}"
```

Now I want to execute it periodically or in the begining of each measure.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-25**:
Could you please post your last edit as an answer instead?

Then accept your own answer. That will convey the fact your question was answered (albeit by yourself) much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I solved it using other type of layer (Spatio Temporal Voxel Layer) and generating a mark layer with the LaserScan topic with a voxel decay of 0.75 seconds. The configuration of the layer is the following:

```
laser_layer_temp:
  enabled:               true
  voxel_decay:           0.75     #seconds if linear, e^n if exponential
  decay_model:           0      #0=linear, 1=exponential, -1=persistent
  voxel_size:            0.05   #meters
  track_unknown_space:   true   #default space is unknown
  observation_persistence: 0.0  #seconds
  max_obstacle_height:   2.0    #meters
  unknown_threshold:     15     #voxel height
  mark_threshold:        0      #voxel height
  update_footprint_enabled: true
  combination_method:    1      #1=max, 0=override
  obstacle_range:        3.0    #meters
  origin_z:              0.0    #meters
  publish_voxel_map:     true   # default off
  transform_tolerance:   0.2    # seconds
  mapping_mode:          false  # default off, saves map not for navigation
  map_save_duration:     60     #default 60s, how often to autosave
  observation_sources:    rgbd1_mark
  rgbd1_mark:
    data_type: LaserScan
    topic: /scan
    marking: true
    clearing: false
    #min_obstacle_height: 0.3     #default 0, meters
    #max_obstacle_height: 2.0     #defaule 3, meters
    expected_update_rate: 0.0    #default 0, if not updating at this rate at least, remove from buffer
    observation_persistence: 0.0 #default 0, use all measurements taken during now-value, 0=latest
    inf_is_valid: false          #default false, for laser scans
    clear_after_reading: true    #default false, clear the buffer after the layer gets readings from it
    voxel_filter: true           #default off, apply voxel filter to sensor, recommend on
    voxel_min_points: 0          #default 0, minimum points per voxel for voxel filter
```

Best regards.
Alessandro

---

Originally posted by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) with karma: 113 on 2020-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0